# How do i get object from localStorage?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get an object that is index and id from localStorage ussing useEffect, so i can get value when website refresh.
but for some reason, it was working at the moment but suddenly, it didn't work.
I know it sounds weird but I don't know what is wrong with my code
this is my code :

```js
  const [panelId_index, setIdIndex] = useState({ index: "", id: "" });

 
  useEffect(() => {
    const persistindex = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("index"));
    if (persistindex) {
      setIdIndex({
        index: persistindex.index,
        id: persistindex.id,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("index", JSON.stringify(panelId_index), [
      panelId_index,
    ]);
  });
```

And plus im using it as like this:

```js
 const { layoutValue, panel } = useContext(CommonStateContext);
  const [changeLayout] = layoutValue;
  const [panelId_index, setIdIndex] = panel;

  const panelId = panelId_index.id;
  const panelIndex = panelId_index.index;
```

this is the result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgypl.png)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the value actually still exist in localStorage?

Comment: when i refresh it , it gets error but i check the localstorage, it's still there exact;y

Comment: In the second `useEffect`, the second param `[ ]` shouldn't that be in the next line , where `useEffect` closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the dependency of the second `useEffect` inside `setItem`. Please try updating it as :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("index", JSON.stringify(panelId_index))
  },[panelId_index]);
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering Sir ! I fix it as u said, however, it got the same result.  I think it's probably different issue ...

Comment: when i refresh it, and I did ( console.log(panelId_index) ) it got empty value.

Comment: Can you try updating the `if` statement to  `if (persistindex.index)` ?

Comment: Thank you so much ! i just did however It didn't work

Comment: i think i found the issue , i use it as like this :  `const panelId = panelId_index.id;` i assume   it can be the issue.

Comment: I don't know how i can fix it tho 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237084/discussion-between-neeraj-tk-and-kim-tech).